# ios tableview back to main view

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

i have created a tableview default app with xcode.

But:

in AppDelegate a add a function to load the table view on Button press.

self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;

that works fine.

in RootViewController a created an array with data, and pass that to the tableview, that works also fine.

in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                          initWithTitle:@"iPad Selected"                         
                          message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"iPad %d", indexPath.row]                     
                          delegate:self       
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"           
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

[image]

i wont on Press on cell, go back to the mainview and set the Lable of the Button with Text from the Table. Maybe also save the ID (row Index) in a variable.

Need help :)

Comment: please elaborate more what actually you want to do what you have tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: I think your main view itself is rootview, so it is root view where your application starts. so where do you want to go back?

Comment: my mainview is the MainWindox.xib I actually dont know how to activate the view. Seminar_AppAppDeletegate is the main file, i think. How to activate a view in another controller

Comment: Check now answer. check that tutorial it will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add another viewcontroller named View2viewController.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     View2viewController *view2 = [[ View2viewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"View2viewController" bundle:nil];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:view2 animated:YES];
     [view2 release];
}
```